# Three.js CSS3D mask object and set CSS3D div style "z-index:-1", it will below objcect，but set background there is no work？

Tags: three.js

I put the videoplayer in the div then bind into the css3D, so i can use the player like floor, and put 3d object on the videofloor.

it works, but css3d mask the 3DObject, then i set CSS3D div style "z-index:-1" someone told me.
but,
i successed only when there is no background in the scene, 3DObject looks like front, css3d behind.
if the scene had background or skybox, CSS3D will be hide;

how to make the skybox and css3D behind both work?

Comment: Instead, you can use `THREE.PlaneGeometry` for the floor, with `floor.material.map = new THREE.VideoTexture( video )`.

Comment: thanks a lot，but i want use the player control like play/pause, not just video